# Can't find class in namespace

Tags: vb.net, class

I have created a class, but when I try to access it using

```
Dim obj As New FabSalesDB.BusinessLayer.DayEnd
```

the compiler can't find it in `FabSalesDB.BusinessLayer` but it can find other classes. What could be the reason?

```
namespace FabSalesDB.BusinessLayer
{
    public class DayEnd : BusinessObjectBase
    {
        public enum DayEndFields
        {
            date,
            CashTaken,
            CardsTaken,
            CashRegistered,
            CardsRegistered,
            CashVariance,
            CardVariance,
            R200,
            R100,
            R50,
            R20,
            R10,
            R5,
            R2,
            R1,
            c50,
            c20,
            c10,
            c5,
            c1
        }
        DateTime _date;
        float _CashTaken;
        float _CardsTaken;
        float _CashRegistered;
        float _CardsRegistered;
        float _CashVariance;
        float _CardVariance;
        int _R200;
        int _R100;
        int _R50;
        int _R20;
        int _R10;
        int _R5;
        int _R2;
        int _R1;
        int _c50;
        int _c20;
        int _c10;
        int _c5;
        int _c1;
        public DateTime date
        {

            get { return _date; }
            set
            {
                if (_date != value)
                {
                    _date = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("date");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CashTaken
        {

            get { return _CashTaken; }
            set
            {
                if (_CashTaken != value)
                {
                    _CashTaken = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CashTaken");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CardsTaken
        {

            get { return _CardsTaken; }
            set
            {
                if (_CardsTaken != value)
                {
                    _CardsTaken = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CardsTaken");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CashRegistered
        {

            get { return _CashRegistered; }
            set
            {
                if (_CashRegistered != value)
                {
                    _CashRegistered = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CashRegistered");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CardsRegistered
        {

            get { return _CardsRegistered; }
            set
            {
                if (_CardsRegistered != value)
                {
                    _CashRegistered = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CardsRegistered");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CashVariance
        {

            get { return _CashVariance; }
            set
            {
                if (_CashVariance != value)
                {
                    _CashVariance = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CashVariance");
                }
            }

        }
        public float CardVariance
        {

            get { return _CardVariance; }
            set
            {
                if (_CardVariance != value)
                {
                    _CardVariance = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("CardVariance");
                }
            }

        }
        public int R200
        {
            get { return _R200; }
            set
            {
                if (_R200 != value)
                {
                    _R200 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R200");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R100
        {
            get { return _R100; }
            set
            {
                if (_R100 != value)
                {
                    _R100 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R100");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R50
        {
            get { return _R50; }
            set
            {
                if (_R50 != value)
                {
                    _R50 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R50");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R20
        {
            get { return _R20; }
            set
            {
                if (_R20 != value)
                {
                    _R20 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R20");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R10
        {
            get { return _R10; }
            set
            {
                if (_R10 != value)
                {
                    _R10 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R10");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R5
        {
            get { return _R5; }
            set
            {
                if (_R5 != value)
                {
                    _R5 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R5");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R2
        {
            get { return _R2; }
            set
            {
                if (_R2 != value)
                {
                    _R2 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R2");
                }
            }
        }
        public int R1
        {
            get { return _R1; }
            set
            {
                if (_R1 != value)
                {
                    _R1 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("R1");
                }
            }
        }
        public int c50
        {
            get { return _c50; }
            set
            {
                if (_c50 != value)
                {
                    _c50 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("c50");
                }
            }
        }
        public int c20
        {
            get { return _c20; }
            set
            {
                if (_c20 != value)
                {
                    _c20 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("c20");
                }
            }
        }
        public int c10
        {
            get { return _c10; }
            set
            {
                if (_c10 != value)
                {
                    _c10 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("c10");
                }
            }
        }
        public int c1
        {
            get { return _c1; }
            set
            {
                if (_c1 != value)
                {
                    _c1 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("c1");
                }
            }
        }
        public int c5
        {
            get { return _c5; }
            set
            {
                if (_c5 != value)
                {
                    _c5 = value;
                    PropertyHasChanged("c5");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `Public DayEnd()` ?

Comment: If no constructors are defined, a public parameterless ctor is automatically created for you.

Comment: Do you have any folder with name DayEnd in your solution?

Comment: Is this new class in a different project/assembly?

Comment: What is the error message u receive when building fail?

Comment: Why is this tagged as c# when its vb.net?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class should have a constructor if you want to use it with Class Var=new Class();

The constructor should be:

```
public DayEnd ()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
```